# Java Swing client server synchronization and not reinventing the wheel to keep consistency

Tags: java, synchronization

I need to implement a proof of concept application Swing application where there's a server having a list of users and several clients which connect to the server and do CRUD operations on the database and hence on the list of users.

[image: client application example]

I have an obvious synchronization dilemma of keeping all clients lists updated so that if one client removed a user another one who still has it in his list cannot change its name.
Now I know a protocol in which before updating a user the client asks the server whether it still exists would work.

However this is just a simple example but in the real application I might have junction tables and complex references between objects which need always to be kept consistent and I don't want to reinvent the wheel.

What I'm wondering if there's some ready made solutions or some library which does this job which doesn't require me to change database or load extremely complex dependencies.

I did some research on Google but nothing seems to fit and the most similar example of client server synchronization I found was "chat programs", however chat programs are inherently simple because a message is never modified or deleted and all you have to keep consistent is the chronological order. I would need something more involved than that or some useful hints on the subject.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is some sort of messaging between server and clients. Clients will either long-poll the server, asking for the updates, or subscribe to some streaming endpoint on your server.

You can take a look on [Comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29) model, long-polling itself, [websockets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket), etc.

Alternatively - there are couple of data management servies - [BlazeDS](http://livedocs.adobe.com/blazeds/1/blazeds_devguide/index.html), [GraniteDS](http://www.graniteds.org/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=16875660) or any similar purpose solution. You can integrate one of those in your application and use for complete data management cycle.

Comment: My application is a desktop application developed in Swing so JavaEE, java FX, websockets etc are out of question. :( I think the problem lies there

Comment: there exist Comet and websocket clients for java

Comment: Anyway, if you want to sync all clients of a server, you need server to send notifications to all it's clients. Hence, you need to implement server push in some way. Maybe, if you google "java server push", you'll find something suitable for your purposes.